# running pandoc from python returns error when run from web but not when run from console

Tags: python, pandoc, cgi-bin, cg

I'm running the following python code to test the automation of the production of epub/html files from pandoc's variant of markdown. When I run this from the web (i.e. using python and cgi), I get a fail and a return code of 83. When I run this from the command line it works perfectly. It needs to run from the web.

The only reference I've found to pandoc and return code 83 relates to pandoc-citeproc: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/rV3eiZhwTlQ

The `runcmd` function below runs from the web in another program to generate pdf/LaTex without any issues.

I've added the error output to the end of this post.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cgi, cgitb, os, tempfile, zipfile, sys, shutil
import yaml, json, subprocess, re, datetime

# Enable module to test/debug CGI issues
cgitb.enable()


def runcmd(*args):

    try:
        result = subprocess.check_output(list(args), universal_newlines=True)
        print("Ran command {} with {} {}".format(args[0], args[1:], result))
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as cpe:
        print(str(cpe))
        print(str(cpe.returncode))
        print(str(cpe.output))
        print("PATH: {}".format(str(sys.path)))
        print("FAIL: {} with {}".format(args[0], args[1:]))
    except OSError as ose:
        print(str(ose))
    except AttributeError as ae:
        print(str(ae))


html_stuff = """Content-Type: text/html\n\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n<title>Generate FYP from Markdown files -- by MF</title>\n<meta charset="utf-8">\n</head>\n<body>\n<h1>Pandoc Test</h1>\n<p></p>\n<div name="messages" id="messages"></div>\n</body>\n</html>"""

print(html_stuff)

test1_args = ['/usr/bin/pandoc', '--smart', '--toc', '--standalone', '--csl=/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/acm-sig-proceedings.csl', '--bibliography=/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/biblio.bib', '--filter=/usr/bin/pandoc-citeproc', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/GeneratedEpubMetadata.yaml', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/GeneratedEpubPreamble.md', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/first_chapter.md', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/another_chapter.md', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/ModifiedEpubAppendix.md', '--output=/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/GeneratedDoc.html']

test2_args = ['/usr/bin/pandoc', '--smart', '--toc', '--standalone', '--csl=/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/acm-sig-proceedings.csl', '--bibliography=/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/biblio.bib', '--filter=/usr/bin/pandoc-citeproc', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/GeneratedEpubMetadata.yaml', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/GeneratedEpubPreamble.md', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/first_chapter.md', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/another_chapter.md', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/ModifiedEpubAppendix.md', '--output=/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/GeneratedDoc.epub']

print("<p>****************\nrunning with test1_args\n****************</p>")
runcmd(*test1_args)
print("<p>****************\nrunning with test2_args\n****************</p>")
runcmd(*test2_args)
```

**Error output:**

## Pandoc Test

****************
running with test1_args
****************

Command '['/usr/bin/pandoc', '--smart', '--toc', '--standalone', '--csl=/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/acm-sig-proceedings.csl', '--bibliography=/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/biblio.bib', '--filter=/usr/bin/pandoc-citeproc', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/GeneratedEpubMetadata.yaml', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/GeneratedEpubPreamble.md', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/first_chapter.md', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/another_chapter.md', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/ModifiedEpubAppendix.md', '--output=/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/GeneratedDoc.html']' returned non-zero exit status 83

83

PATH: ['/var/www/cgi-bin', '/usr/lib/python3.2', '/usr/lib/python3.2/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python3.2/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

FAIL: /usr/bin/pandoc with ('--smart', '--toc', '--standalone', '--csl=/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/acm-sig-proceedings.csl', '--bibliography=/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/biblio.bib', '--filter=/usr/bin/pandoc-citeproc', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/GeneratedEpubMetadata.yaml', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/GeneratedEpubPreamble.md', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/first_chapter.md', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/another_chapter.md', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/ModifiedEpubAppendix.md', '--output=/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/GeneratedDoc.html')

****************
running with test2_args
****************

Command '['/usr/bin/pandoc', '--smart', '--toc', '--standalone', '--csl=/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/acm-sig-proceedings.csl', '--bibliography=/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/biblio.bib', '--filter=/usr/bin/pandoc-citeproc', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/GeneratedEpubMetadata.yaml', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/GeneratedEpubPreamble.md', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/first_chapter.md', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/another_chapter.md', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/ModifiedEpubAppendix.md', '--output=/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/GeneratedDoc.epub']' returned non-zero exit status 83

83

PATH: ['/var/www/cgi-bin', '/usr/lib/python3.2', '/usr/lib/python3.2/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python3.2/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

FAIL: /usr/bin/pandoc with ('--smart', '--toc', '--standalone', '--csl=/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/acm-sig-proceedings.csl', '--bibliography=/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/biblio.bib', '--filter=/usr/bin/pandoc-citeproc', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/GeneratedEpubMetadata.yaml', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/GeneratedEpubPreamble.md', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/first_chapter.md', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/another_chapter.md', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/ModifiedEpubAppendix.md', '--output=/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/GeneratedDoc.epub')

Comment: Error code 83 is an error running a filter, if that helps narrow things down.

Comment: Thanks. Figured that it was to do with filter. Tested it with any reference to filter or biblio stuff removed. Works fine from web. Question is: why would filter behave differently when run from web rather than command line?

Used parameters:

`test3_args = ['/usr/bin/pandoc', '--smart', '--toc', '--standalone', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/GeneratedEpubMetadata.yaml', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/GeneratedEpubPreamble.md', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/first_chapter.md', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/another_chapter.md', '/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/ModifiedEpubAppendix.md', '--output=/tmp/tmp0u5dtk/GeneratedDoc_nobib.epub']`